# How to remove the "_embedded" property in Spring HATEOAS

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Boot and HATEOAS to build a REST API and when my API returns a collection, it is wrapped inside a "_embedded" property, like so:

```
{
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/technologies"
      }
   },
   "_embedded":{
      "technologies":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "description":"A",
            "_links":{
               "self":{
                  "href":"http://localhost:8080/technologies/1"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "description":"B",
            "_links":{
               "self":{
                  "href":"http://localhost:8080/technologies/2"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want the response to be like this:

```
{
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/technologies"
      }
   },
   "technologies":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "description":"A",
         "_links":{
            "self":{
               "href":"http://localhost:8080/technologies/1"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "description":"B",
         "_links":{
            "self":{
               "href":"http://localhost:8080/technologies/2"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

My TechnologiesController:

```
@RestController
@ExposesResourceFor(Technology.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/technologies")
public class TechnologiesController {
    ...
    @ResquestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.xpto-technologies.text+json")
    public Resources<Resource<Technology>> getAllTechnologies() {
        List<Technology> technologies = technologyGateway.getAllTechnologies();
        Resources<<Resource<Technology>> resources = new Resources<Resource<Technology>>(technologyResourceAssembler.toResources(technologies));
        resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(TechnologiesController.class).getAllTechnologies()).withSelfRel());
        return resources;
    }
```

The configuration class has the annotation @EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL).

What is the best way to produce the response without the "_embedded"?

Comment: If you remove `_embedded` from the response then the response will no longer be valid HAL. You either need to stick with `_embedded` or use a different media type.

Comment: The HAL draft says "The reserved "_embedded" property is OPTIONAL"

Comment: It's optional in that a resource doesn't have to have any embedded resources. However, if it does, then they should be beneath `_embedded`.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  I have a projection on an object, and am limiting it to only display the name.  The problem is that there are over 20 relations, so the _embedded object is huge.  I haven't found a good way to overcome this either.

Answer (score 10):

I close HAL feature, because it is hard to using Resources/Resource by restTemplate. I disable this feature by following code:

```
public class SpringRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(false);
    }
}
```

It work for me. HAL is good if there are more support with restTemplate.

Comment: it works but actually doesnt solve the problem at all. Instead of returning the data inside `_embedded` field it creates a `content` field which is better but doesnt create the `technologies` field required by the author;

Answer (score 9):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/10012cfddc5479ee9a5cbe98bfe4f76483965bd1/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/hateoas/HateoasProperties.java#L32,L33) says

> application/hal+json responses should be sent to requests that accept
>   application/json

In order to omit `_embedded` in you response you'll need to add

```
spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false
```

to `application.properties`.

Comment: I did it. but, unfortunately, it still exists

Answer (score 6):

Adding this `Accept` header to the request:

```
Accept : application/x-spring-data-verbose+json
```

Comment: For me this returns a `406` with the message: "Could not find acceptable representation"

Answer (score 3):

For those who use Spring Data, and consider it as a problem - solution is to set

```
spring.data.rest.defaultMediaType = application/json
```

in application properties. 
There still links will be available, but no _embedded any more.

Comment: This did not change anything for me.

Comment: This removed _embedded from the request however, added "content" instead. the true rest interface should return "technologies" instead. no ?

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing in the produced and expected results are semantically different things. The former thing is the HAL representation of a `Collection<Technology>`. The latter, which you expect is the representation of:

```
class Wrapper {
  Resources<Technology> technologies;
}
```

Note how this is how we actually create the top level `technologies` property that you would like to see in your response. You don't create any of the latter in your controller. A top-level `Resources`instance is basically a collection and the only way to represent a *top-level* collection in HAL is `_embedded`. Apparently you don't want that but that's what you have written in your controller method.

Assuming you have `Wrapper`, something like this should work (untested):

```
Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(assembler.toCollectionModel(technologies);
EntityModel<Wrapper> model = EntityModel.of(wrapper);
model.add(linkTo(…));
```

PS: As of Spring HATEOAS 1.0, `Resources` is `CollectionModel` and `Resource`is `EntityModel`.

Comment: This answer, though untested, goes beyond a configuration change that doesn't address the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in the service

```
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  retrieveAllStudents(){
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`http://localhost:8080/students`);
  }
```

This will deal with the _embedded part of Json and extract the desired data.

```
export class ListStudentsComponent implements OnInit {

 // declaring variables to be used
  student: Student;
  students: Student[];
  message: string;

  // injecting student service into the constuctor
   constructor(
    private studentService: StudentService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshStudents();
  }
refreshStudents(){
  this.studentService.retrieveAllStudents().subscribe(
     response => {
       console.log(response);
      this.students = response._embedded.students as Student[];
     }
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest versions in Spring `RepositoryRestConfigurer` doesn't include the method `public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config)` you'd need to override the default method on RepositoryRestConfigurer  which include cors parameter.

```
public class RestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.setDefaultMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        config.useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType(false);
    }
}
```