# Jackson serialize the object with additional "content" and "links" when using Hateoas

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson, hateoas

I am using Hateoas in my project and it works well.

But Jackson works unexpectedly. I always getting additional fields "content" and "links" when I call `objectMapper.writeValueAsString()`.

For example I have a class that has only the fields "pattern" and "keyword"

```
public class AutoFillAssistantWord {
      Pattern pattern;
      String keyword;
}
```

But I get the result when the object of `AutoFillAssistantWord` is serialized to json.

```
   {
         "pattern" : null,
         "keyword" : null,
         "content" : [ ],
         "links" : [ ]
   }
```

I find the fields are added by some hateoas methods while debuging the serialized process. Look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Anyone please suggest how to avoid the additional fields on json.

Comment: if you don't want the links field, why are you using hateoas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808220/how-to-remove-the-embedded-property-in-spring-hateoas might be helpful

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It doesn't work, so I just leave the fields there.