# Migrating to Spring Boot 2.2.0 @JsonIgnore does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

Migrating to Spring Boot 2.2.0, all the properties with the `@JsonIgnore` annotation are now serialized in the API Rest Body (while in Boot 2.1.9 worked fine).
Furthermore, an `"_embedded"` attribute is added before each nested object.

It seems a Jackson issue.

Details of the code:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, of = { "makeId", "modelId", "versionId", "bodyTypeId", "modelYear" })
@ToString(callSuper = true, of = { "makeName", "modelName", "versionName", "bodyTypeId", "modelYear" })
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(schema = "fleet", name = "vehicles", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id", "make_id", "model_id", "version_id", "body_type_id", "model_year", "port_number" }) })
public class Vehicle extends BaseEntity implements VehicleBaseMakeInfo {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicleRef", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();

    @Length(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "make_id", length = 250)
    private String makeId; // UK_1

    @Length(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "make_name", length = 250)
    @NonNull
    @NotBlank
    private String makeName;

    @Length(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "model_id", length = 250)
    private String modelId; 

...
```

Once I execute the GET request "http://localhost:8081/api/vehicles"

I receive

```
{
        "id": 105,
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "enabled": true,
        "avatarDocumentId": null,
        "makeId": "Bmw",
        "makeName": "Bmw",
        "modelId": "X4",
        "modelName": "X4",
        "modelNameOriginal": null,
        "versionId": "Executive",
        "versionName": "Executive",
        "bodyTypeId": "Wagon",
        "engineCapacity": 2.0,
        "fuelingId": "Unleaded",
        "power": 184.0,
        "co2": 2,
        "detailedTransmissionId": "Manual",
        "tractionName": "4x4",
        "portNumber": 3,
        "urbanCycle": 4.3,
        "extraUrbanCycle": 3.8,
        "mixedCycle": 4.0,
        "price": 27000.0,
        "annualFringeBenefit": null,
        "fringeCustomValue": false,
        "modelYear": 2016,
        "sourceType": "CUSTOM",
        "inProduction": true,
        "fringeAlgMatchingState": null,
        "fringeMatchingCorrection": null,
        "requiredReviewType": null,
        "fringeSimilarVehicleId": null,
        "useType": "PASSENGER_TRANSPORT",
        "correctToCreateAsNew": false,
        "productionStartDate": null,
        "productionEndDate": null,
        "calculatedMonthFringeBenefit": null,
        "fullVersionExtended": "Bmw X4 Executive Wagon 3p 4x4 Unleaded 2016",
        "calculatedAnnualFringeBenefit": null,
        "objectId": "105",
        "_embedded": {
          "cars": [
            {
              "id": 258,
              "state": "INSTALLED",
              "enabled": true,
              "avatarDocumentId": null,
              "contractVersions": [
                {
                  "id": 308,
                  "state": "ACTIVE",
```

As you can notice, the "_embedded"and "cars" should not be present.
Before upgrading to Boot 2.2.0 It worked fine

Thanks

Antonio

Comment: can you show the code with complete input and output example

Comment: Added the details in the post, thanks

Comment: can you add this to application.properties file and check, `spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false` Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28808220/2987755

Comment: I've tried but it still continue to have both problems

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.1 the problem is solved